# Trying to use pip to install my Python package that I uploaded to PyPI, getting "No matching distribution found for"

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I'm new to python, trying to figure out how to create a simple package, upload to PyPI, then download using PIP.

Source: https://github.com/shane-kercheval/kerlib

I tried: python setup.py register

Seemed to work, result:

```
running register
running egg_info
writing top-level names to kerlib.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing requirements to kerlib.egg-info/requires.txt
writing kerlib.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to kerlib.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'kerlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'kerlib.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running check
Registering kerlib to https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
```

So, to test it out, I created a temp directory, created a virtual environment (`virtualenv -p python3 venv_kerlibtest`), activated the virtual environment (`source venv_kerlibtest/bin/activate`), and then tried to download via pip (`pip install kerlib`)

and got

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kerlib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for kerlib
```

I also got the same thing when I tried packages that clearly didn't exist, like `pip install asdfasdfasdfldsf`.

Thoughts?

Comment: Your package is [listed on pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kerlib/1.0.1) but it is empty.  Did you forget to run `python setup.py sdist upload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just running `python setup.py register` isn't enough; that just creates an entry for your project on PyPI. You also need to run `python setup.py sdist bdist_egg upload` to upload your code (from `sdist`) and a binary distribution (from `bdist_egg`) to the repository. This needs to be done every time you need to release a new version.

Answer (score 0):

For me, That is because I used an unofficial pypi repo (https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple) to speed up download speed because of the existing of GFW.

And this repo did not sync with the PyPI central repo without delay.

For this reason, please use the official repo or just wait for some minites.